# Created a new Lookup - is that an error on step #6?

Tags: setup

I created a new Lookup field on oppty, on the step that assigns the Related list, It relates to field.
Is that a mistake? I never actually read that paragraph. First time I noticed this.

[image]

Comment: You are right, I would say that those 2 full lines belong to step 5 and not step 6
From "Select the page layouts that should include this field" all the way until the page layout.".  It is talking about the field and not the Related List

Comment: yes, amazing, I am a salesforce admin for 14 years, this is the first time I read that paragraph :-)